# VS Code TypeScript Issue with Extending Jest Matchers

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, ts-jest

I've created custom Jest matchers to extend expect for use with AxiosResponse objects. Despite following the standard approach for extending Jest's matcher types, TypeScript is not recognizing my custom matchers.

The TypeScript error in VSCode is:

```
Property 'status' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<AxiosResponse<any, any>>'.ts(2339)
```

I've tried several approaches to resolve this, but so far, none have worked.

1. Created a custom type declaration file `jest-custom-matchers.d.ts` with the following content:

   ```
   import 'jest';

   declare global {
     namespace jest {
       interface Matchers<R> {
         status(expectedStatus: number): R;
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Ensured that the tsconfig.json is correctly configured to include the types directory:

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"],
     },
     "include": ["src/**/*", "types/**/*"]
   }
   ```
3. Restarted the TypeScript server in VS Code and checked for any conflicting type definitions.
4. Moved .d.ts file to root as per [VSCode does not recognize jest custom matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68488335/vscode-does-not-recognize-jest-custom-matcher)

Tests run successfully using the command line, but VS Code does not recognize the custom matchers.

[image: VSCode Custom Matcher TS Error]

Comment: "status" isn't a very idiomatic matcher, the assertion doesn't read well. `toHaveStatus` maybe, although `toHaveProperty("status", ...)` would achieve the same. Similarly perhaps `toMatchSchema`.

Comment: That's just an example I provided. The main concern I have is figuring out how to eliminate the TypeScript error in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I had to add the `specs` directory in the `include` in `tsconfig.json` and that did the trick!

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "specs/**/*",
    "types/custom-matcher.d.ts"
  ],
```